# neo4j query when call apoc from browser get chrashed

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

the browser got crahsed when execute this line of code:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) = 22481941 CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n,{maxLevel:1}) YIELD nodes, relationships RETURN relationships,nodes
```

the error is below:

Something went wrong: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" and the application can't recover.

when I inspect the browser the console said :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
at main.chunkhash.bundle.js:1
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at main.chunkhash.bundle.js:1
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at Object._ (main.chunkhash.bundle.js:1)
at Object.extractNodesAndRelationshipsFromRecordsForOldVis (main.chunkhash.bundle.js:1)
    at e.value (main.chunkhash.bundle.js:1)
    at e.value (main.chunkhash.bundle.js:1)
    at Ll (vendors~main.chunkhash.bundle.js:61)
    at Il (vendors~main.chunkhash.bundle.js:61)
```

but if executed from postman it's just fine. is there something wrong with my code or just its a bug from neo4j?[image]

Comment: This looks like a javascript error not a neo4j one. Which versions of Neo4j, APOC, and the Neo4j Browser are you using?

Comment: yes, its javascript error. the query been executed with neo browser client, not with neo desktop client. so the javascript error  come from neo4j modules. i just suspect, may there is some error of may query that trigger neo4j js module to be crashed.

Comment: ive used neo4j 3.5.3. 
neo4j browser 3.2.16
with APOC 3.5.0.1 version

Comment: Could you provide the smallest possible dataset on which this happens as well as the output from Postman?

Comment: JSON from POSTMAN
[
{
        "year": "2017",
        "usage": "SPD MOTOR",
        "type": "VEHICLE",
        "police_region": "JAWA TENGAH",
        "registration_no": "G05129281I",
        "nik": "9243010906640004",
        "colour": "PUTIH-BIRU",
        "engine_no": "JMNBV-1078905",
        "license_plate": "LM 3002 JH",
        "name": "ANU",
        "model": "SPD MTR SOLO",
        "brand": "HONDA",
        "engine_capacity": "110.00",
        "id": "22502758"
    },
    {
        "nik": "9243010906640004",
        "id": "5139671",
        "type": "PERSON"
    }
]